# What would happen to superpowered people on Zur-En-Arrh that are human?

Tags: dc

What would happen to super powered people on the planet Zur-En-Arrh that are human?

E.g. Blue Beetle, Major Force, Shazam, Green Lantern, Planet Master, The Flash, The Spectre, Raven?

Comment: Your last question appears to be a separate distinct question in its own right so I have edited it out, you should ask it as a new question. On top of that I'm not sure if this is too broad as it stands, it seems to me that it would affect each of the superheros differently so a new answer would be required for each. However, I'm not that familiar with DC so won't VTC yet,

Answer (score -1):

Planet Master would be affected the same as any other normal human man. If you watch the *Batman the Brave and the Bold* episode where Batman raves Green Arrow to stop some escaped criminals. Then as Green Arrow is falling behind the Bat, Batman gets warped to the planet Zurr En Arrh and gains the powers of Superman but has a weakness of yellow Kryptonite.

Then later in the same Batman Brave and the Bold episode Green Arrow is warped to the planet and also gains the powers of Superman. When they return back to Earth though they lose the Superman powers that they had on Zurr En Arrh.

As for the others:

Raven is mostly human so she would be affected the same like any normal human woman albeit with also her demon powers.

Shazam would gain Superman powers in his mortal normal boy human form but as to if his lightning would then be able to be Shazamed down to turn him into Captain Marvel would be hard to say due to him not being the True Billy Batson because the lightning might not recognize that its the same Billy.

Green Lantern’s Kyle Rayner and half Jordan would be affected normally gaining Superman powers for the time on the planet, Alan Scott is unknown because he gets powers from the starheart though presumably would also be the same.

The Flash would gain Superman powers while on Zurr En Arrh.

Spectre unknown and the rest would be unknown as to what would happen to them.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for some of these that this is the case I.e. you state the Flash confidently but offer no evidence. Are you going purely off of the cartoon episode?